# multiple numbers combination

Tags: perl, numbers

Using Perl, how to create all possible combinations of numbers from range `1..20`, where a combination can contain a set of numbers from 1 to 15 numbers at a time.

To exemplify:

List for case where elements can contain all possible combinations of 1 number at a time in range `1..20`:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Example of list for case where elements can contain all possible combinations of 2 numbers at a time  in range `1..20`:

```
1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 1 5, ..., 2 3, 2 4, ..., 19 20
```

Example of list for case where elements can contain all possible combinations of 3 numbers at a time in range `1..20`:

```
1 2 3, 1 2 4, ..., 2 3 4, 2 3 5, ..., 18 19 20
```

Example of list for case where elements can contain all possible combinations of 5 numbers at a time in range `1..20`:

```
1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3 4 6, ..., 2 3 4 5 6, 2 3 4 5 7, ..., 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need [`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm%3a%3aCombinatorics)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(combinations);

for (combinations([1..5], 3)) {
    print "@$_\n";
}
```

[`Math::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math%3a%3aCombinatorics) can also do the job, but the interface isn't as intuitive.  It can be better for large return sets though, as it returns an iterator instead of all of the combinations at once.

Comment: Fantastic! Couldn't be simpler. Thank you.